# Dynamics AX 2012 - adding a custom query based report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have created a SQL Server query using Transact-SQL and added it directly to the database as a view.

Then I created a SQL Server Reporting Services report using that query. Now I want to access this report from Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012. I have no idea how to do it. 
As far as I know one has to create a query in AX, then create an AX report, deploy it to AOT and once it's there you can use it in the application.

Do you know a way to use a custom SQL query without writing it again in AOT? My query is pretty complex and it could be impossible to rewrite in AOT.

Answer (score 4):

Prerequisites:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Microsoft Dynamics AX Visual Studio Tools installed.
- Microsoft Dynamics AX client configured.
- SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) (Add-on for Visual Studio).

Create a *Report Server Project*.

Add the *.rdl* file downloaded from SSRS server: right click on *Reports* node -> *Add* -> *Existing item ...*

Adjust other parts of the report, like datasources.

Right click on the report project -> *Add [project name] to AOT*.

[image: Add [project name] to AOT.]

The report should be now available in AOT:

[image]

Go to *AOT -> SSRS Reports -> Reports* -> Right-click *[Your report] -> Deploy element.*

You can now create Output menu items which point to your report.

Comment: How can I open my report in Visual Studio? The report is deployed to SSRS and I can export it as a .rdl file. Visual Studio doesn't seem to accept this type of file.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875252/is-it-possible-to-import-existing-ssrs-reports-in-visual-studio) question, you should be able to import the report into a Visual Studio and recreate datasources.

Comment: I have the rdl file but I can't import it to the Visual Studio project because there is no "Add existing item" option in the menu. I think it is because of these AX plugins for VS.

Comment: It seems that you need  SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to create Report Server Project in VS2010 which can add *.rdl files. Updated the answer.